# The view profiles.views.ProfileDetailComment didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

I am trying to process a form in generic detail view. I am using [this django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#using-formmixin-with-detailview) to make this view. In this view I am showing all the info and post by the profile model. and anyone visiting this profile can comment on the post of this profile
Here is my view:

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect, render
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.views import View
from django.views.generic import DetailView, RedirectView, UpdateView, FormView
from django.views.generic.detail import SingleObjectMixin
from .models import Profile
from posts.forms import PostModelForm, CommentModelForm
from posts.models import Post
from relationships.models import Relationship


User = get_user_model()

class ProfileDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):

    model = Profile
    slug_field = "slug"
    slug_url_kwarg = "slug"
    form_class = CommentModelForm
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs): 
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        
        
        sender_profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, id=self.request.user.id)
        receiver_profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, id=self.object.id)
        frnd_btn_state = Relationship.objects.relation_status(
            sender=sender_profile,
            receiver=receiver_profile,
        )
        context['frnd_btn_state'] = frnd_btn_state

        context['frnd_req_rcvd'] = Relationship.objects.invitation_recieved(
            receiver = sender_profile
        )
        context['form'] = CommentModelForm()
        return context
    

class ProfilePostComment(SingleObjectMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'profiles/profile_detail.html'
    form_class = CommentModelForm
    model = Profile

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        comment_form = CommentModelForm()
        profile=Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        if 'submit_c_form' in request.POST:
            comment_form = CommentModelForm(request.POST or None)
            if comment_form.is_valid():
                instance = comment_form.save(commit=False)
                instance.user = profile
                post_id = request.POST.get('post_id')
                instance.post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
                instance.save()
                comment_form = CommentModelForm()
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("profiles:detail", kwargs={"slug": self.request.user.username})         

class ProfileDetailComment(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = ProfileDetailView.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = ProfilePostComment.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)


profile_detail_view = ProfileDetailComment.as_view()

class ProfileUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):

    model = Profile
    fields = ["name", 'bio', 'gender', 'country', 
        'favourite',
    ]

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("profiles:detail", kwargs={"slug": self.request.user.username})

    def get_object(self):
        return Profile.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        messages.add_message(
            self.request, messages.INFO, _("Infos successfully updated")
        )
        return super().form_valid(form)


profile_update_view = ProfileUpdateView.as_view()


class ProfileRedirectView(LoginRequiredMixin, RedirectView):

    permanent = False

    def get_redirect_url(self):
        return reverse("profiles:detail", kwargs={"slug": self.request.user.username})


profile_redirect_view = ProfileRedirectView.as_view()
```

the error I am getting is

```
ValueError at /profiles/sddhruvo/
The view profiles.views.ProfileDetailComment didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/profiles/sddhruvo/
Django Version: 3.0.10
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
The view profiles.views.ProfileDetailComment didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Exception Location: /home/sddhruvo/Desktop/django/stalker/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response, line 126
Python Executable:  /home/sddhruvo/Desktop/django/stalker/env/bin/python
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:    
['/home/sddhruvo/Desktop/django/stalker/stalker_project',
 '/usr/lib/python37.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/sddhruvo/Desktop/django/stalker/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages',
 '/home/sddhruvo/Desktop/django/stalker/stalker_project/stalker_project',
 '/home/sddhruvo/Desktop/django/stalker/stalker_project/stalker_project']
Server time:    Fri, 25 Sep 2020 23:26:57 +0000
```

I can't understand this error. and why this is happening as I am following django official documentation.

Comment: Your `post` method does not return a `HttpResponse` in the `ProfilePostComment`...

Comment: Thank you. Though it was clear in the error I was still acting like blind person. working for like 12 hours straight. I added my own answer below

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. I had to import HttpResponseRedirect by
`from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect`
and after post method I had to add this line

````
return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.path_info)```
````